# Can anyone identify this pusher biplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

[image]

This plane was probably built around 1912. I do not know by what company built this. Does anyone know what airplane this is?

Comment: Similar: [Maurice Farman 6bis](https://www.flickr.com/photos/varese2002/14963340053).

Comment: I don't personally know what plane this is, but if you're really determined to find out, I'd recommend Wikipedia's [List of Pusher Aircraft by Configuration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pusher_aircraft_by_configuration) as a good place to start.

Comment: For kicks, who can identify the plane in the background?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like a Farman Aviation Works design but many builders copied the Farman designs.

Most Farman aircraft had straight boxed struts but some had staggered wings and slanted struts:

Maurice Farman biplane
[image]
Source: http://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft28602.htm#tabs-1

[image]
Source:  [ebay auction](http://www.ebay.com/itm/FARMAN-3-SEAT-BIPLANE-At-the-French-Military-Trials-Rheims-France-1911-RP-/371424887006)

Also similar to the MF.9
[image: http://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft28795.htm]

Source:http://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft28795.htm

Comment: Also: [this](http://www.corpusetampois.com/che-20-1916aviateuranonymeecolefarmann.html) and [this](http://www.hydroretro.net/etudegh/premiersfarman.pdf) (in French). The three Farman brothers have been very active.